# Como dibujar lineas sobre una imagen en un imagview y guardarlo

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código, me dibuja las líneas, pero si quiero guardarla o mostrarlo en otro `ImageView`, solo se muestra/guarda las líneas, yo quiero guardar la imagen con las líneas dibujadas. O de que otra manera puedo dibujar esas lineas sobre la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void Lineas(){
    BitmapDrawable drawable =(BitmapDrawable)imgviewImagenOriginal.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmapimg= drawable.getBitmap();
 
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapimg.getWidth(), bitmapimg.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));

    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    int startx = bitmap.getWidth()/2;

    int starty = bitmap.getHeight();

    int endx = bitmap.getWidth()/2;

    int endy = 0;

    canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, endx, endy, paint);


    int startx1 = 0;

    int starty1 = bitmap.getHeight()/2;

    int endx1 = bitmap.getWidth();

    int endy1 = bitmap.getHeight()/2;

    canvas.drawLine(startx1, starty1, endx1, endy1, paint);


    imgviewCanvas.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    Guardar_Canvas();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas dibujar las lineas sobre la imagen, crea una clase que extienda de `ImageView` (`AppCompatImageView`) y esta dibuje sobre la imagen las lineas horizontal y vertical sobre la imagen.

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

public class CustomImageView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {

        public CustomImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

            //Linea horizontal
            canvas.drawLine(0, this.getHeight()/2, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight()/2, p);

            //Linea vertical
            canvas.drawLine(this.getWidth()/2, 0, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight(), p);

        }
}
```

Dentro de tu layout define esta clase definiendo el paquete donde se encuentra:

```
<com.jorgesys.views.CustomImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    ...
    ... />
```

Carga la imagen y se dibujaran sobre esta las lineas horizontal y vertical:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]